# how to get data attribute value from link tag?

Tags: jquery

I am using some Html  and jQuery code. I want to get `data-name` value from link tag. 
Below is my link code that I am using:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){

    console.log($(this).data("name"));
    });

});
</script>
<a class="dz-cover" href="javascript:undefined;" data-name="cover" data-dz-remove="">Make Cover</a>
```

When i click on link tag my jquery code is below   `console.log($(this).data("name"));`  but it giving me undefined what i do where i am wrong please help me

Comment: `$('.dz-cover').click(function() { console.log($(this).data("name")); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to wrap in a click event
2. You need to cancel that click event too
3. Please get rid of the ugly JavaScript href now you cancel the click

Like this

```
$(function(){
  $(".dz-cover").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log($(this).data("name"));
  });
});
```

Using

```
<a class="dz-cover" href="plsenablejs.html" data-name="cover" data-dz-remove="">Make Cover</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dz-cover").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("data-name"));
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: and yes you can use console.log($(this).data("name")); also